# Is there a way to pass multiple dynamic sql values from a select query in JCL to a REXX?

Tags: mainframe, jcl, rexx

I have a select query in a JCL. For eg:  the select query will fetch 130 rows with 6 columns.  I need to pass the values of each row one by one to a REXX using the JCL.  Is there a way to do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not save the result to a file and read the file in rexx ???

Comment: you need to write them to a file, its really the only way. Then have the rexx routine parse through the columns.

Comment: Thanks to you both.  I will try to write into a file and then parse it.